# image height 100% comes out larger than div

Tags: html, css, image, height

I'm trying to make an image inside a div that is always 100% of the height, with the width proportional. But when I set the height to 100% it comes out larger than the `div`. Am I misunderstanding what height 100% means?

Here's the css:

```
#whoami_bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 26%;
    width: 45%;
    height: 35%;
    background: rgba(50, 204, 239, 0.4);
}
#whoami_bg img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="whoami_bg">
    <br /> <a href="whoami.html">
        <img src = "images/whoami_image.gif" />
    </a>
</div>
```

It does scale, but it scales too big. This happens in chrome and safari at least. I have tried giving the image a `class = "whoami"` and putting the style in an `img.whoami` tag, but it works the same. For some reason my images have decided to give 110%. :P

It seems simple; how do I make my image 100% the height of my `div`?

Comment: Have you tried using max-height instead of height. (max-height:100%;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this tag from your code:

```
<br />
```

It pushes your `<a>` with the content down and it overflows it's parent container.

Comment: @user3557096 : Glad to help you!Mark as answered, please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to SO and the user interface here is impenetrable. How do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: user3557096: There is a outline of a checkmark left to my answer under the score of the answer, you should click on it to accept answer (checkmark will become green after clicking on it)

Answer (score 4):

Your `<br />` tag is disrupting the flow of these elements. In general, you should avoid using these except for text-only elements. Removing this tag fixes the height issue:

```
<div id = "whoami_bg">
    <a href = "whoami.html">
        <img src = "images/whoami_image.gif" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvgff/)**